# Как реализовать очередь сообщений для телеграм бота на C#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, очередь

Всем день добрый! Пишу телеграм бота на C# с библиотекой TelegramBOT Api. Узнал в документации, что бот может отправлять только 30 сообщений в секунду. В голове возникла идея с очередью, которая будет каждый тик программы проверять себя на наличие сообщений и если они есть, то отправлять их пользователям. Но на деле, сообщения иногда отправляются не в том порядке, в котором они в попали в очередь, да и её проверка через цикл while во время работы программы, мне кажется, не очень хорошая практика. Какие существуют методы реализации?

Comment: Мб использовать https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: Версия .NET какая? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/

Comment: Вариантов решения уйма, и `Queue<T>`, и каналы (`Channel`), и даже вон относительно недавно появились [ограничители](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/) разных видов. Берите что вам ближе и используйте) Касательно цикла, его обычно не крутят вечно (хотя и такие бывают реализации), а запускают крутиться при появлении одного объекта, и крутят до тех пор, пока в очереди не закончатся объекты, после чего метод завершает свою работу до тех пор, пока в очередь не поступит кто либо еще.

Comment: Если вы планируете отправлять 30+ сообщений в секунду, то, возможно, есть смысл озаботиться брокером сообщений, наподобие rabbitMq или kafka, чтобы при перезапуске вашего бота вы не теряли неотвеченные сообщения и чтобы вы могли бы запустить больше ботов разгребать очередь.